# Android ArrayAdapter constructor not taking generic objects?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, arraylist

I'm having issues with an Android AutoComplete dropdown menu.  I am trying to pass a custom object into a new ArrayAdapter, which is then used for the data in the dropdown menu.  However, I'm getting the following error for this line of code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_context, R.layout.list_item, list_items);

The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int, DropdownItemData[]) is undefined
```

I've tried running this as well, which outputs a type mismatch error:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DropdownItemData>(_context, R.layout.list_item, list_items);

Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayAdapter<DropdownItemData> to ArrayAdapter<String>
```

However, the following *does* work just fine:

```
String[] test_list = new String[] {"some", "test", "data"};
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_context, R.layout.list_item, test_list);
```

My DropdownItemData class overrides the Object toString() method, as is recommended in the ArrayList documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Does anyone know what the issue is/what I'm missing?  According to the docs, the constructor I'm trying to use for ArrayList should just be taking a generic list--so I don't understand what the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class name is `ArrayAdapter<T>`. And the constructor signature is `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`.

So if you declare your variable as an `ArrayAdapter<String>`, you must pass an array of `String` as last argument of the constructor.

To be able to pass it an array of `DropdownItemData`, your adapter must be of type `ArrayAdapter<DropdownItemData>`.

You can put a lion in a `Cage<Lion>`, and a bird in a `Cage<Bird>`. But you may not use a `Cage<Lion>` with birds, nor a `Cage<Bird>` with lions.

You should read the [generics tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: Actually, I get an error even if I change it to ArrayAdapter<DropdownDataItem>--it still is wanting a string.  I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Make sure the variable is *declared* as a ArrayAdapter<DropdownItemData>. ArrayAdapter<DropdownItemData> adapter; //... ; adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DropdownItemData>(_context, R.layout.list_item, list_items);

Comment: ArrayAdapter<DropdownDataItem> is not the same as ArrayAdapter<DropdownItemData>